# Angular change form value to lowerCase

Tags: angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        login: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
    });
```

and I would like to change anything that is in `form.value.login.toLowerCase()`. How can I do that with `get()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use angular pipes -> [Link](https://angular.io/api/common/LowerCasePipe)

example from the official website:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lowerupper-pipe',
  template: `<div>
    <label>Name: </label><input #name (keyup)="change(name.value)" type="text">
    <p>In lowercase: <pre>'{{value | lowercase}}'</pre>
    <p>In uppercase: <pre>'{{value | uppercase}}'</pre>
  </div>`
})
export class LowerUpperPipeComponent {
  // TODO(issue/24571): remove '!'.
  value !: string;
  change(value: string) { this.value = value; }
}
```

What do you mean with: "How can I do that with get()"

**edit after your comment:**

If  you want to send it in lowercase just use js's str.toLowerCase() in your .ts file before sending it to the service - simple as that.. ;)

Comment: I mean like: this.form.get('login'). I would like to change the value to lowerCase before sending it.